# java's executeUpdate is not working properly

Tags: java, oracle

I have the following java code:

```
if (ps.executeUpdate() != 1)
  {
    // Error - did not insert one row
    String err = "insert unable to insert LocalUsage data: " + usg.toString();
    Logger.log(err, _MODULE_CLASS, Logger.DEBUG);
    throw new DaoException(err);
  }
```

The problem if the query had a foreign key exception, then it will be thrown but it will never get to inside the if. what should I do so that it will get inside the if and output the log I have?

The problem is that this if condition is inside a try catch block, and it is going to the catch and never enters to the if condition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`executeUpdate()` might throw an `SQLException`, as is described in its API documentation. You might want to catch that exception.

```
int count;
try {
    count = ps.executeUpdate();
} catch (SQLException e) {
    throw new DaoException("Exception while executing update: " + e.getMessage());
}

if (count != 1) {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeUpdate%28java.lang.String,%20int%5b%5d%29) states executeUpdate() may throw an exception so your code flow will fail and you will not be able to do any processing afterwards incase your exception handling is not proper.

Which I think is happening in your code right now.

While doing database call I would suggest you do it like this:

```
int operationStatus;
try {
  operationStatus = ps.executeUpdate();
} catch(SQLException exp) {
    final String message = "SQL Exception while calling executeUpdate()";
    logger.error(message, exp);
    throw new DAOException(message, logger);
} catch(Exception exp) {
    final String message = "Exception while calling executeUpdate()";
    logger.error(message, exp);
    throw new DAOException(message, logger);
}  finally {
   //you may wish to clean up resources if they are not going to be used after this point.
}

if(operationStatus < 0) {
  //Next steps
}
```